# Modificar el valor de un bean al inyectarlo en otro bean diferente

Tags: java, xml, spring, batch

Estoy intentando inyectar una propiedad en un tasklet bean que envia correos, esta propiedad es el asunto y varía dependiendo de el entorno de ejcución.

Mi idea es crear un bean String, inyectarlo en el writer y modificarlo, para despues enviarlo con el nuevo valor al tasklet anterior.

El problema es que el writer lo midifica pero pero a la hora de inyectarlo en el tasklet este conserva el valor incial.

No se como puedo hacer para modificar este valor y que se conserve a la hora de inyectarlo en el tasklet de envio de correos. La inyecciones la tengo que realizar via xml.

Gracias

```
 <bean class="java.lang.String" id="asuntoCorreo">
    <constructor-arg value="XXX"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un bean, la propiedad String es final y aunque la intentes modificar en el writer, no tiene efecto alguno.
Debes generar un POJO con este string, y este POJO es el que debes enviar de salida de un proceso a la entrada del siguiente proceso.

Un saludo